# Components using MUI in shared library not using parent app theme

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I have two apps using MUI, each has a theme. I have a separate npm package containing components used by both apps. This works fine except when I import a component from my npm package, it doesn't use the theme of the app consuming it, it appears to just use the default theme (as the separate package has no theme defined). Is there a way of ensuring the shared components imported from my npm package use the theme of the consuming app?

Thanks!

Comment: See [CssBaseline](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-css-baseline/) ...